# Git Push invalid username and password

Tags: git, github

I created a repository on Github.com , then i cloned it locally successfully.

But when i try to push it keeps giving an Error:

`remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MosabAhmed/BostonHousePrice.git/'`

I went through all the possible solutions. including generating Access Tokens.

the problem is im not able to get into the code snippet that asks for for the credentials in order to provide the access token i generated .

```
Git clone https://github.com/MosabAhmed/BostonHouse.git
Cloning into 'BostonHouse'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), 5.97 KiB | 5.97 MiB/s, done.
```

when trying to push i get

`remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MosabAhmed/BostonHousePrice.git/'`

Comment: I think you have some bad credentials stored in the credential manager and so they are automatically provided to git. You should remove these credential saved. Search how to do it because it's OS specific (for windows it's in the 'credential manager').

Answer (score 1):

The URL you set as the remote in your `git clone` command does not include any username, so GitHub treats it as anonymous - and while that is fine for cloning and pulling from public repos, that isn't suitable for pushing to any repo (public or private).

You can fix this by adding your username to the remote: `git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/MosabAhmed/BostonHousePrice.git`